# Data is not saving to CSV in PHP FOPEN function. Saves Page HTML instead

Tags: php, csv

I have spent many hours on this and keep getting the same results. I have this code to save data to a CSV file and prompt to save the file once you click "Send to CSV" on a wordpress page template. It is basically a submit button and the search date field. If it is submitted, it will run this script and open the file to save as a csv file. But the data itself in the csv file is not the queried data. Instead, it saves the entire page template from header to footer starting with < !DOCTYPE html >...< /html > along with the data... I know the query is working. I can echo the data and it also shows up in the csv along with all of the HTML script. I only want the data and not the entire page html. Anything I am doing wrong here? The results should be the following:

Column
Joe Smith
John Doe
Jack Smith
Etc...

BUT instead I am getting 
< !DOCTYPE html >...EVERYTHING INSIDE THE HTML...< / html >

```
if ($submitbtn == 1) {

 // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
 header('Content-type: text/csv');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Attendees.csv"');

 // do not cache the file
 header('Pragma: no-cache');
 header('Expires: 0');

 // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
 $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

 // send the column headers
 fputcsv($file, array('Column'));

   /* Gather Data for CSV */
   $dt = strtotime(str_replace(',', '', $searchdate));
   $year = date('Y',$dt);
   $month = date('F',$dt);
   $day = date('d',$dt);

    $args = array(  
   'post_type' => 'loghistory',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'date_query' => array(
    'year'  => $year,
    'month' => $month,
    'day'   => $day,
    ),        
   'orderby'                => 'date',
   'order'                  => 'desc',
   'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

  $myQuery = new WP_Query($args);

 if ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) :  

  $count = 0;       

  while ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) : 

   $myQuery->the_post();  

     $thetitle = get_the_title();
     $thetitle = str_replace(',',' | ', $thetitle); 
     fputcsv($file, $thetitle);


 $count++;   

 endwhile; 

 endif; 

 wp_reset_postdata();
 readfile($filename); 
 }
```

Comment: First make sure that no html or other output happens before the PHP code. Then add an `exit;` after the last `readfile($filename)` to prevent further output.

Comment: Adding exit(); worked along with @unclexo foreach statement. I turned the query into an array and added the foreach statement outside the loop. I also moved the code before the header. Thank you! It's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `fputcsv()` function should be an array but you were passing a string. Look at the following working code example:

```
<?php

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Attendees.csv"');

// do not cache the file
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

if ( $file ) {

    // send the column headers
    fputcsv($file, array('Column'));

    /* Gather Data for CSV */
    // $dt = strtotime(str_replace(',', '', $searchdate));
    // $year = date('Y',$dt);
    // $month = date('F',$dt);
    // $day = date('d',$dt);

    // $args = array(  
    //  'post_type' => 'loghistory',
    //  'post_status' => 'publish',
    //  'date_query' => array(
    //      'year'  => $year,
    //      'month' => $month,
    //      'day'   => $day,
    //  ),        
    //  'orderby' => 'date',
    //  'order' => 'desc',
    //  'posts_per_page' => -1
    // );

    // $myQuery = new WP_Query($args);

    // if ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) :

        // $count = 0;

        // while ( $myQuery->have_posts() ) :


        $titles = ['Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3'];

        foreach ( $titles as $title ) :

            // $myQuery->the_post();
            // $thetitle = get_the_title();
            // $thetitle = str_replace(',',' | ', $thetitle);

            // Notice the second argument which must be an array
            fputcsv($file, [$title]);

            // $count++;
        endforeach;     

        // endwhile;

    // endif;

    // wp_reset_postdata();
}

fclose($file);
```